# Create a Branch Programmatically from C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I've been tasked to create work items and branches in VSTS from within our C# application. I've seen many examples for creating a work item and I was able to do it myself using the libraries (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client & Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client). So far I've only seen one example creating a branch in TFS 2013, but I could not follow along since the CreateBranch method is now obsolete (according to the documentation). I was also unable to find the TeamFoundationServer class in these libraries.

```
public void CreateBranchWithComment(string serverUrl, string sourcePath, string targetPath, string comment)
{
  var tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(serverUrl);
  var vcServer = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

  var changesetId = vcServer.CreateBranch(sourcePath, targetPath, VersionSpec.Latest);

  var changeset = vcServer.GetChangeset(changesetId);
  changeset.Comment = comment;
  changeset.Update();
}
```

Is it still possible to create branches via the REST API or libraries? If so, could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this functionality is only available from the SOAP methods. I missed the TfsTeamProjectCollection class when I read the documentation. Because I was solely focusing on REST API, I paid little attention to anything related to the SOAP methods and examples.

According to the documentation the TeamFoundationServer class is obsolete since Visual Studio 2010, however the CreateBranch method is still available in the VersionControlServer class.

To retrieve an instance of the VersionControlServer class, you must call GetService from a TfsTeamProjectCollection instance. Include the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient Nuget package.

For Example:

```
var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(accountUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));
var vcServer = server.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

/*
 * See documentation for this class at:
 * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver(v=vs.120).aspx
 */
var changesetId = vcServer.CreateBranch("$/Demo/Main","$/Demo/Dev/Branch", VersionSpec.Latest, null, "Branch Comment", null, null, null);
```

See the TfsTeamProjectCollection class documentation for more information.