# Azure DevOps - How to programmatically create branches within a pipeline task using TFVC

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm in search for some help on how to use TFVC commands within a Pipeline task to automatically create a new branch from an existing branch.

I need to find a way to take a copy of our golden copy code base and move it to a new branch for developers to work on.

Is there a way to do this using Pipelines and TFVC commands and\or REST API commands?

Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. I went through az devops cli, REST API and native client. And I just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785471/create-a-branch-programmatically-from-c-sharp but it refers to 2013 version.

Comment: have you seen this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-command?view=azure-devops  That could get you commands but what you probably want is this.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/install?view=vsts-cli-latest

Comment: There is no such REST API to create branches within a pipeline task using TFVC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/branches/get%20branches?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1. But we could use Branch Command to create a branch and use Client Object Model Reference if you want to manage the Version Control programmatically. Just use the "CreateBranch()" method in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer class to create a branch.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648448/vsts-rest-api-for-creating-tfvc-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say what you are looking for is this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/install?view=vsts-cli-latest

you should be able to install that onto the pipeline machine via a step.

That should then get you a cli so you can run the commands.  Then you should be able to use this link to help complete the task
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-command?view=azure-devops

Comment: How do you create a new branch? The documentation doesn't show how to leverage your credentails and create branch

Comment: Did you see this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/authenticate?view=vsts-cli-latest

Comment: Vsts for git repos only allows you to create branches, not tfvc reops

Comment: To me this looks like it should, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branches-command?view=azure-devops unfortunately, I do not have access to TFVS.